# How to post wordpress functions for my loop in an accordion

Tags: php, wordpress, css, loops, accordion

So I'm trying to create a vertical accordion and with each section of the accordion, I want there to be a blog post. So essentially, i'll have an accordion with 5 of the latest posts. In each post, I'll include the day, month and year and the title of the post as well. I'm assuming these i'll do with spans or some other markup using PHP, but when i add the below standard loop to my accordion, each way i've tried yields different, but not what i wanted outcomes. I'm thinking for the id="ac-1/2/3/4.." i'll have to come up with a ascending number or something with PHP?

```
    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile;

        else :
            echo '<p>Nothing here!</p>';

    endif;
```

---

```
<section class="ac-container">
    <div>
        <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-1">Blog Post 1</label>
    <article class="ac-small">
        <p>Blog Post 1 Content</p> 
    </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" checked />
        <label for="ac-2">Blog Post 2</label>
    <article class="ac-medium">
        <p>Blog Post 2 Content</p>
    </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-3">Blog Post 3</label>
    <article class="ac-large">
        <p>Blog Post 3 Content</p>
    </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-4">Blog Post 4</label>
    <article class="ac-large">
        <p>Blog Post 4 Content</p>
    </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

Anyone get what I'm saying? I can get outputs with those loop functions, but it doesn't come out right because i believe each input with a different ID causes confusion. This is in my header.php of course.

Much appreciated for your time/help.

Comment: Why do you want ids with ascending numbers - wht do you use the ids for?

Comment: I'm simply taking a css3 accordion and trying to turn it into a blog with wordpress functions. I don't necessarily need asc id numbers, that's just how the accordion was set up. What do you suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a simple counter variable:

```
<section class="ac-container">
<?php
$counter = 0;
if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-<?php echo $counter;?>" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-<?php echo $counter;?>"><?php the_title();?></label>
    <article class="ac-small">
        <?php the_content();?> 
    </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>Nothing here!</p>';

endif;?>
</section>
```

Comment: That's incredible! Thank you. I'm trying to teach myself PHP, this is amazing. So, when I added that to my header.php, obviously i have my index.php with the loop, so now i have the accordion and a loop. If i delete, the loop on index, the site disappears. If i add your code to header.php, it just stacks on top of the loop. How can i display just this accordion? Or should i leave that for a single paged php file and design around the accordion and set my site to say a static page?

Comment: You should only use the loop once on a page (eg in index.php, or page.php, single.php etc) - if this is going in the header (to be repeated on every page), then it would probably be better to iterate the results of a call to `get_posts`.

Comment: Please note that if you are trying to teach yourself php, wordpress is not a good start. Though very popular, its codebase is somewhat bloated, and encumbered (due to backwards compatibility concerns) with an architecture thats 10 years old. the "wordpress loop" structure is a good example of this, as are the magic `the_*()` functions

Comment: I've noticed that. Steve, thanks for the words. I'll focus more on PHP rather than WordPress for sure. Take care.